# java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio gave error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

it was working fine on Windows os and
i imported code to macos and i can't run it anymore
tried changing kotlin version
tried changing gradle version
nothing seems to work

My Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nrp.sbja"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'



    def room_version = "2.2.6"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"
    testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"


    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'

    

    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    

}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
'''


project level gradle- 
'''
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha02"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'

        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        /* maven {
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/amulyakhare/maven'
        }*/
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update Moshi to 1.13.0: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1368
(Answer from: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50768)

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem too,
first commented :

```
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```

then all its apply to and sync project after that clean and remove comments the

Comment: Removed kept and got another error in rooms database